# SQL Database Structure for Users + Memberships + Groups

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm developing an e-commerce site and I wanted to get this community's thoughts on a database structure for groups, users, and their memberships.

**THE GOAL:** Determine a user's group membership(s) and access privilege at login. A user could be a seller on this site, an admin, a site support, or ANYTHING. Must be scalable.

**INITIAL THOUGHT:** Three separate tables: `users`, `groups`, and `memberships`. At a successful login, search the membership table for the user's ID and get group ID's from that same row in the membership table. From there, another query to get group information from the groups table (like name of group, description, etc). Store the memberships in the user's session and call it a day.

**THE CONCERN:** At log in, I don't want to unnecessarily perform additional queries. The above "initial thought" consists of 3 separate queries at login.

---

**THE QUESTIONS:**

- Is this the right approach?
- Any better design solution(s)?
- Better to break admins into their own table, or toss 'em into the same `groups` table?

Answer (score 0):

The database design is reasonable. As a user can belong to multiple groups and can have multiple memberships, two additional tables `USER_GROUP` and `USER_MEMBERSHIP`to hold the relations between users and groups and between users and memberships will be necessary.